# ArrayList removeAll

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following arraylists:

```
ArrayList<Obj o> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to remove all of the elements from list1 that have (string)ID that equals the elements from list2.

```
if(o.getId().equals(one of the strings from list2)) -> remove.
```

How can I do that with removeAll or some other way without having to write an additional for. I'm searching for the most optimal way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think even removeAll internally uses a loop, so I don't think you'll get any better than `for (Iterator it = list1.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) { if (list2.contains(it.next().getId()) it.remove(); }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using java 8, you could do:

```
ArrayList<YourClass> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.removeIf(item -> list2.contains(item.getId()));
// now list1 contains objects whose id is not in list2
```

Assuming `YourClass` has a `getId()` method that returns a `String`.

---

For java 7, using `iterator` is the way to go:

```
Iterator<YourClass> iterator = list1.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (list2.contains(iterator.next().getId())) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that seems to be the best way, but I get error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7...

Comment: @Vluis if it is solved, don't forget to accept the answer that helped!